# cellForRowAtIndexPath getting the right data under each section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm stuck with a problem populating an `UITableView`. 
I have got an `NSMutableArray` with `customers`. It looks like this:

```
customer
    first letter="A"
    customer name="Adwars Inc."
customer
        first letter="A"
        customer name="Amman Co."
customer
        first letter="B"
        customer name="Building Inc."
customer
        first letter="C"
        customer name="Computer Co."
```

So I've got an object customer, which separates me each customer. And i've got some keys for each object. 
In my second NSArray i've got all my first letters, which appear in my customer data. It look like this:

```
A
B
C
D
G
J
M
S
Z
```

I was able to get my right section count and rows in section, but when i try to populate my table view it always look like this:

[SCREENSHOT](http://files.beger.org/iOS%20Simulator%20Bildschirmfoto%2029.04.2012%2014.44.16.png)

HERE IS MY CODE

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

for(int i = 0; i < [firstletters count]; i++)
{
    if (indexPath.section == i) {

        for(int count = 0 ;count < [customers count]; count++)
        {

        NSString *firstletter;
        NSString *key;

        key = [firstletters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        firstletter = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"FirstLetter"];
            if ([key isEqualToString:firstletter]) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"S_NAME1"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"s_town"];
            }

        }
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

What do i have to do to make it work?

Comment: `UITableViewCell`s `-initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` is deprecated since ages.

Comment: I added another answer just to propose another way to do this with a different data structure -- I don't know if this could work for your purposes, but it might be a different way to think about the organization of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every cell, you're iterating through all the customers, repeatedly setting (and resetting) the textLabel and detailTextLabel for *every* customer whose first letter matches the current section (but you're not considering whether the index of that customer in that section matches the current indexPath.row or not). This means that in your code every cell will have the textLabel and detailTextLabel for the last customer whose first letter matches the current section's first letter.

Comment: okay i see what you mean. IS there a way to make it match? how can i make the indexPath.row match my customer index and section index? Thank you!

Comment: You could do it a number of ways. You could loop through your customers and find then find the n-th item (where n is the indexPath.row) that has the first letter that matches that for your current section. Or you could use a customer index that is equal to your indexPath.row plus the sum of the row counts for all the prior sections. A whole bunch of ways of skinning the cat.

Comment: Thanks robert! "Or you could use a customer index that is equal to your indexPath.row plus the sum of the row counts for all the prior sections." ... same idea in my head :)  im just trying to figur out the row count of all proir sections? sorry i'm a newby haha

Comment: No offense, but I'm not going to write the code for you. (I feel like I'm doing someone's homework for them.) Try writing the code yourself, and if you're really stumped, then post your attempt (e.g. edit your original post, appending your attempt at the end) and we'll see if we can nudge you in the right direction. (By the way, your code above might lend itself to my first suggestion, "loop through your customers and find then find the n-th item (where n is the indexPath.row) that has the first letter that matches that for your current section").

Comment: Sorry Robert, i was a little frustrated. I Got it to work though. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but I just wanted to offer another thought on how this might be done with data structured in a different way.  If you had a dictionary where the keys were the first letter of your customers' names, and the values were the customer objects whose first letter was the same as the key, then you wouldn't have to do any looping (I don't know if you're still doing that in your solution).  I made an example project (to see if this would work) that structures the data this way, except that my "objects" are just the names of companies rather than customer objects.  In my table view controller I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.companyDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *aArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Abercrombie & Fitch",@"Altera",@"Agilent",@"Allelix",@"Abbott Laboratories", nil];
    NSArray *cArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CocaCola",@"Continental",@"ConocoPhillips", nil];
    NSArray *mArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Myriad Genetics",@"Myrexis",@"Microsoft",@"McDonald's", nil];
    NSArray *nArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nokia",@"NPS Pharmaceuticals",@"Norelco",@"Netflix",@"Nextel",@"Navistar International", nil];
    [self.companyDict setValue:aArray forKey:@"A"];
    [self.companyDict setValue:cArray forKey:@"C"];
    [self.companyDict setValue:mArray forKey:@"M"];
    [self.companyDict setValue:nArray forKey:@"N"];
    self.keys = [[self.companyDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.keys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.companyDict valueForKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:section]]count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSArray *theArray = [self.companyDict valueForKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS (Copy and paste this code):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"CustomerCell"] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = nil;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;       
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < [firstletters count]; i++) {
        if (indexPath.section == i) {
            for(int count = 0 ;count < [customers count]; count++) {
                cell.textLabel.text = nil;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

                NSString *firstletter = nil;
                NSString *key = nil;

                key = [firstletters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                firstletter = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"FirstLetter"];

                if ([key isEqualToString:firstletter]) {
                    cell.textLabel.text = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"S_NAME1"];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[customers objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey: @"s_town"];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! Unfortunatly it doesnt work. it wont show anything. :) only the last customer starting with Z

Comment: Here is a ScreenShot [link](http://files.beger.org/iOS%20Simulator%20Bildschirmfoto%2029.04.2012%2015.29.40.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [TableKit](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit) library. 
This case the solution will be clean and elegant:

```
NSMutableDictionary* sectionMap = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:30];
for(NSDictionary* c in customers) {
    NSString* firstLetter = [c objectForKey:@"FirstLetter"];
    NSString* name = [c objectForKey:@"S_NAME1"];
    NSString* town = [c objectForKey:@"s_town"];

    TKSection* section = [sectionMap objectForKey:firstLetter];
    if(!section) {
        section = [TKSection sectionWithCells:nil];
        section.headerTitle = firstLetter;
        [sectionMap setObject:section forKey:firstLetter];
    }

    TKCell* cell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle text:name detailText:town];
    [section addCell:cell];
}

self.sections = [sectionMap allValues];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i would like to solve the problem using standard libaries. If it doesnt work, i will try using custom ones! :)